# Can you say 'make friends' using 作る？

Tags: meaning, set-phrases, phrases

I'm directly translating from Eng so I'm wondering if　作るworks. I'm only familiar with ~と友達に成りたい　＆　友達ができたい。

Comment: You might consider asking a separate question about できたい as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem.

「友達{ともだち}**を**作{つく}る」 is a very comon phrase meaning "to make (new) friends".

As always, just be careful with your ***particle*** choices.

「友達**に**なる」

「友達**が**できる」

Among the three particles in **bold** above, no two are interchangeable.